# Git: Remove irrelevant commits from history after subtree split

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-commit, git-subtree

I have repo `personal_stuff.git` which I used to store a whole bunch of early-maybe-not-quite projects.

Every now and then one of them takes off, and I have to split a subfolder from `personal_stuff/coolnewthing` into its own `coolnewthing.git` repo.

To do this I use

`git subtree split -P personal_stuff/coolnewthing -b coolnewthing`

and then pull the new branch from another new git directory via:

`git pull ../../../../personal_stuff coolnewthing`

This works great, but I have all these commits in my history related to files that no longer exist.

How do I filter these out and keep only the commits relevant to the files that I still have?

Comment: You could use "git rebase -i"

Comment: Not sure if I understand the docs, but I'm not adding a feature branch to a main one - I'm doing the opposite. Does this still apply?

Comment: switch to the new branch do a **git rebase -i HEAD~<number of commits you wanna clean up>** and use the interactive rebase menu. The solution given by @joran seems good use that.

Comment: I should add that this isn't a new branch anymore, it's a completely new repo - just has commits from the previous repo it used to be part of

Comment: Thats ok, it'll still work, but do try **git rebase -i** it's a brilliant tool :)

Comment: I did, but it had no effect - irrelevant commits are still in my git log :(  @joran's answer did the trick though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a new clone from the original repo and select a new root directory for this new local repo

```
git clone <url-to-personal_stuff.git> coolnewthing
cd coolnewthing
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter coolnewthing
```

Note: the origin of this new local repo is still `url-to-personal_stuff.git` so you need to change the origin before you push

```
git remote set-url origin <url-to-coolnewthing.git>
```

Comment: Is this better than subtree splitting? I quite like your method, but I've already split off my subdirectory. `cd coolnewthing; git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter ./` tells me that `refs/heads/master is unchanged`

Comment: you need to run `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter` from top level

Comment: I am, but `coolnewthing` is already its own repo, so it can't filter `personal_stuff` for coolnewthing. I think....

Comment: Aha - `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter <relative/location/in/old/repo/folder>` did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: I should also add that due to my last commit in `personal_stuff` being the deletion of the `coolnewthing` subdirectory, the last commit related to just that subfolder in the new repo had no files in it (!!!) Easy solution, `git-log` find the last commit where you still have files, and then `git reset --hard <commithash>`. Then to update the new remote, you do `git push --force origin master`. Easy....